# Use of "to-be-<something>"

Tags: grammar, meaning

Someone I know be a doctor soon, and I want to address this person with its future title but emphasising that s/he is not yet a doctor, so if I say that

> to-be-Dr. Alice

Would that be meaningful ?

For example, I saw a similar usage in Star Wars Clone Wars: A droid addressed Asoka as Jedi, but she responded saying that she is not yet a Jedi, and then the droid addressed back to her as something like

> soon-to-be-Jedi

or

> to-be-Jedi

(I don't remember exactly)

Comment: Usually "to be" comes after the future title or status. Such a usage would be jocular and unofficial. A person is either a doctor or not a doctor. Informally people call (e.g.) a pregnant woman a "mother-to-be"

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that there is a widely recognised usage for this purpose. We do have titles such as

> President-elect
>
> acting-CEO
>
> Chairman-designate
>
> once and future King

but I think such formulations have evolved piece-meal rather than emerging from some grammatical rules.

I think your idea of

> soon-to-be-Dr Alice

is rather charming and entirely obvious in meaning. I do think you need the **soon** because the process of becoming a Doctor is quite lengthy and I think you intend to emphasise that becoming a Doctor is imminent.

We could attempt to be more formal:

> Dear Alice.
>
> I so look forward to the day when I can write "Dear Dr Alice!"

But I prefer your idea if this is a relatively informal letter.

Comment: There is also “Doctor-to-be.”

Comment: Doctor-in-training ?